centering an image or object in an image using numpy arrays and whatnot
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = Image.open("image.png")

pixels = list(img.getdata())

pxl_array  = np.array(pixels)

print(len(pxl_array))

pxl_array_norm = pxl_array//255

height, width = pxl_array_norm.shape
total_intensity = np.sum(pxl_array_norm)

centroid_x = 0.0
centroid_y = 0.0

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        centroid_x += x * pxl_array_norm[y, x]
        centroid_y += y * pxl_array_norm[y, x]

centroid_x /= total_intensity
centroid_y /= total_intensity

print(f"Center of character: ({centroid_x}, {centroid_y})")

offset_x = img.width // 2 - centroid_x
offset_y = img.height // 2 - centroid_y


this is the code so far and i got stuck here where i dont know how to "move" the background to the center of the shape or vice versa the picture is enter image description here
i tried some different stuff with altering code for close enough goals i found but nothing i really tried worked im looking for some tips then maybe code since im still only learning to get used to python and the libraries on it

Your code is incorrect. And not very efficent. But more importantly incorrect.
Your image is a RGBA color image. So, your pxl_array is a 204300×4 array. So, all your computation are made as if you had a 204300×4 black & white image. The thing that makes the output almost consistent, is because you are using img.width and img.height as reference at the end, and that one are the real dimensions.
For a while I thought that the problem was that the image was black&white on your machine, and the color was only in the posted image.
But that is not so: if your image was indeed a 2D grayscale image (L format in PIL talk), the your pxl_array would have been a 1d array of scalars, and the rest of the code would have failed on an error.
Getting pxl_array correctly
So 1st correction: the way you get pxl_array
pxl_array=np.asarray(img)[...,:3].mean(axis=2)

is sufficient (I get the 3 1st channels, since the 4th is transparency, which is irrelevant, and turn it into grayscale, by taking the mean).
A more portable way (but you asked for numpy) is to rely on PIL functions, since we have them
np.asarray(img.convert('L'))

It as the advantage to works even if image had another format (for example if it is already grayscale. Or if it is RGB)
Computing centroid more efficiently
The whole point of numpy is to avoid python for loops at all cost
I can see two ways to do the same computation.
The first one, translating your for loops using numpy broadcasting
y=np.arange(height)
x=np.arange(width)
centroid_y = (y[:,None]*pxl_array_norm).sum() / total_intensity
centroid_x= (x[None,:]*pxl_array_norm).sum() / total_intensity

It computes y*pxl_array_norm and x*pxl_array_norm for all values of x and y, and sum the result (could have used mean as well)
Another way, more direct
centroid_y, centroid_x = np.argwhere(pxl_array_norm).sum(axis=0)/ total_intensity

or
centroid_y, centroid_x = np.argwhere(pxl_array_norm).mean(axis=0)

But those rely on the fact that your pxl_array_norm is binary (either 0 or 1). When your code (and my first) would work even if you had different level of intensity in pixels, and wanted the brightest pixels to weight more.
Centering the image
# I need offset_* to be integer
offset_x = int(img.width / 2 - centroid_x)
offset_y = int(img.height / 2 - centroid_y)

# Depending on sign of offset, we have to truncate the beginning or the end 
# of what we copy on the new 0 image
y1=max(-offset_y, 0)
y2=min(height, height-offset_y)
x1=max(-offset_x, 0)
x2=min(width, width-offset_x)

out=np.zeros_like(pxl_array)
out[y1+offset_y:y2+offset_y, x1+offset_x:x2+offset_x] = pxl_array[y1:y2, x1:x2]

plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()


